# How many Skill points does a Drake Companion get?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, animal-companions

The page for [Drake Companions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions/drake-companions) seems to be contradictory, or I'm missing something:

- The table lists Skills starting at 3, then 6 etc based on the Charge (PC's) class level
- The description of the Drake's Skill's is "for each Hit Die it has, it gains a number of skill ranks equal to 6 + its Intelligence modifier"

Is one accurate and the other errant, or is the Table's in addition to the Drake's Skills from HD?

Comment: For the record, this is not a sounding board for reasons Drake Companions are a terrible choice nor awesome, I'm just looking to know the correct number of Skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Both are correct

Drake companions gain **6 + int modifier** skill ranks per HD.

However, the table already takes into consideration the *Starting Statistics* of a drake companion, listed on the following page:

> **Drake Starting Statistics**
>
> Size Tiny; Alignment any nongood; Speed 20 ft.; Attack bite
> (1d3), tail* (1d3); Ability Scores Str 8, Dex 17, Con 11, **Int  4**,
> Wis  10, Cha 7; Languages Draconic. *This is a secondary
> natural attack; see page 182 of the Pathfinder RPG Core Rulebook
> for more information on how secondary attacks work.

As we know, [a creature with 4 int has a -3 int modifier](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Intelligence-Int-), and thus they gain 3 skill ranks per HD due to that penalty. If you happen to increase the companion's int score to 6 (possibly at 10th level), this modifier also changes and they would, instead, gain 4 skill ranks per HD.

There is **an error on the table**, however, when the ranks increase even when the companion HD does not, unlike it happens on the [druid's animal companion table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions/). The companion should not gain skill ranks when they do not gain HD. You will notice that feat's follow the standard rules and they gain one new feat every odd HD (3, 5, 7, etc).

Comment: I didn't even consider that was an error, I just accepted it and gave my drake the number of skill points it said...I guess I'll be having a chat with my GM.

Comment: I didn't think you could get less Skills than the base. I also avoid making stupid characters, so it doesn't come up much. It's interesting that they didn't follow the HD since the other columns are accurate.

Comment: The minimum is 1 skill point per HD/level, which is what happens to animals and vermin.